# jQuery Toggle issue with responsive design

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I have a responsive design that I collapses three columns into one (but still keep three categories apart within this column) and and I toggle the categories to show and hide the content in each category.

My issue is however that once you re-size the browser window to see the three columns floated beside each other again, the value display:none; is still there.

```
/************************************************************************************
smaller than 990
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {

    .sn{
    display: block;
    margin: 25px;
    }   

}

/************************************************************************************
smaller than 720
*************************************************************************************/
@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    .sn {
    display:none;
    }
}
```

jQuery code for the Toggling:

```
// Start function when DOM has completely loaded
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $open = $();
    $('#wb .cat_responsive').on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $open.slideUp();
      $open = $(this).closest('.sn_cat').find('.sn');
      $open.not(':animated').slideToggle();
    });
    $('.cat_responsive').get().hideFocus = true;
});
```

Comment: In practice, users are rarely going to be resizing their browser window just to fiddle with your design (with the possible exception of smartphone users switching from landscape to portrait). The idea is to lay it out in whatever format is most convenient for their CURRENT browser window size.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of display:none, try using:

```
visibility:hidden;
visibility:visible;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when using .toggle(), jQuery adds the 'display: block' directly to the HTML tag, not to the css file.

Example:

Let's say your element is:

```
<div id="mini-navLinks">
```

When you use jQuery .toggle() it becomes:

```
<div id="mini-navLinks" style="display: block">
```

or

```
<div id="mini-navLinks" style="display: none">
```

I'm sure you can see the problem already; these attributes are stuck to your element. So even though you still have the 'display: none' property set in your CSS, when the browser resizes it's going to read from the style given in the element's tag.

I just ran into this problem myself, and I've written a quick hack to fix the issue using a few lines of jQuery:

```
    $(window).resize(function() {   
        if($(window).width() > 769)
        {
             $('#mini-navLinks').hide();
        }
    });
```

Depending on which elements you are toggling, you'll have to hard-code them into jQuery with the specified screen width that they should become hidden. Using the above code jQuery will .hide() my #mini-navLinks element once the user's browser has become greater than 769 pixels wide. The method .hide() will work even if it's already hidden, so no need for any extra checks.

I agree with Blazemonger in that users will rarely resize the browser to fiddle with the design, but I think it's still nice to not leave any loose ends. Also, this was a quick fix, if anyone else has a better solution I'd be interested to hear more.